# npm module implementing pattern for wrapping shell commands?

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

I'm looking for an npm module for wrapping shell commands in modern application style api's.

I came across this module -- https://github.com/mattijs/node-rsync -- which provides a nice fluent-style api around the rsync command.  Peaking at the implementation, it looks very much like this pattern could be easily re-used for wrapping other shell commands.  It occurs to me this must be a common need -- before I code, I thought I'd search ...  Does anyone know of an npm module that implements a general pattern for wrapping specific shell commands in a nice fluent api?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of an npm module that implements a general pattern for wrapping specific shell commands in a nice fluent api?

[child_process built-in module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

Obviously, different commands use different argument syntax, so you can't do better than that.